# Making a struct in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I came across code with the following format:

```
class A {
   typedef struct {
      // variables of struct B
   } B
  // private and public variables, member functions of  class A
}
```

What is the point of putting a struct in a class instead of outside of it ?

And who gets to access the struct if it is placed in a class ?
Only the class or can another class use it too ?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: The code you came across is a poor example. Rule of thumb: any place where you see C++ code that reads `typedef struct ...`, that means that whoever wrote it either cargo-culted a bunch of C code without a full understanding of it, or simply does not know C++, or a combination of the two.

Comment: In this case `B` is `private`. No one but `A`  is allowed to use it. I would do this with a type I don't want exposed to the outside world, like a node class in a linked list.

Comment: Can you make B seen by both A and C ? suppose A and C are both list classes that use nodes and B is a node struct ? Could I use the same hidden struct for both ?

Comment: No matter what tricks you pulled to eliminate duplicate code, they would be different classes, `A::B` and `C::B`. You wouldn't be able to share the nodes back and forth without casting.

Comment: @HusamChekfa You can make `C` a friend class of `A` and then inside `C` you can use `A::B` (And have a type alias `using B = A::B;` so you can use `C::B` for convenience). You can also have the definition of `B` outside of `A` and have the type alias in both classes for a similar effect

Comment: Or make a `class Base { protected: struct B {} };` and inherit `Base` in both `A` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

in C++, an 'inside' class is essentially under a 'namespace' of the outer class.
That is, you access it using `A::B` from anywhere, as long as it is public.

It's not like Java where the inner class is related to a pointer of the outer class. You don't need an `A*` to have an `A::B*`.
They have no low-level connection and the inner class cannot see anything in the outer class without a given outer-class pointer.